# SQL Server 2017 Installation fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to install a new instance of a SQL Server using Sql Server 2017 Setup. I keep getting an error by Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client, as follows:

[image]

So far, I've tried...

1. running Windows Installer troubleshooter suite (no problems detected)
2. the workaround provided in windowscentral.com/how-fix-network-resource-unavailable-install-error-windows-10; (I tried multiple versions; they won't install due to various reasons

[image]

3. entering an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'sqlncli.msi' (didn't work: the file is not a valid installation package

[image]

4. downloading sqlncli.msi and trying to enter the alternate path to it instead (didn't work).

How can I make this work?

Comment: One of your screenshots has Microsoft SQL Server 2012, which is odd if you are attempting to install Microsoft SQL Server 2017.  So the obvious question is, have you tried to download the installer again for 2017, I would also remove 2012 if that has already been done.

Comment: That's the 2012 Native Client that Sql Server 2017 is dependent on so I should not uninstall it. But I'll download the installer again for 2017 and try again.

Comment: Downloading a new installer worked.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to install a new instance of a SQL Server using Sql Server 2017 Setup. I keep getting an error by Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client

The error you have recieved is an indication that the installation is incomplete and missing a vital resource that does not exist on your system.  This can easily be solved by downloading the `Sql Server 2017 Setup` and trying again.  I personally would uninstall everything MS SQL Server related before attempting this solution.